# Why do I have more rep in meta than I do on Gaming?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, user-accounts

As you can see, my rep on the [meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22551/outlaw-lemur) is 125, But on [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/22551/outlaw-lemur), is 75 because I placed a bounty on a question. Why is my rep higher on the meta than it is on the actual site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta takes a while to update. Don't worry. It'll catch up soon enough.

Comment: Why can't I accept your answer for a minute?

Comment: @OutlawLemur To give other people time to answer; seeing the question has been solved can discourage some people from adding another answer, but often it's useful to have more information.

Comment: @MatthewRead that makes sense, also if there is then a better answer posted.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There was a major reshuffle of meta sites a few years ago which (among other things) appears to have ultimately fixed* the rep-sync issue.

<sub>* Well, apart from *one* place thanks to an [unrelated bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317269/179041)</sub>